# Download of Node 7.9.0 failed with myeclipse ide for Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, myeclipse

Downloaded and installed `myeclipse` without problems, but when I try to create a new angular project out of the gate I get Download of Node 7.9.0 failed, but that's what I already have installed.

```
dp$ node -v
v7.9.0
```

Comment: You may need to configure eclipse proxy settings in MyEclipse. Check this forum topic for other tips: https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/project-creation-fails/

Comment: Installing with npm, selecting help -> update shows no version cl 4 available ??

Answer (score 0):

The proxy support has been added to the CI 4 release. So please update to that release and that should fix this problem. Click Help->Check for Updates and follow instructions.

Comment: Help->Check for updates does not allow the updating to 4, just one through three. Thats using the download listed on the genutec page

Comment: Sorry. In that case, you're likely already at CI 4 (you can check by looking at Help->About MyEclipse...). Did you try other tips mentioned in the Genuitec forum: https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/project-creation-fails/

Comment: This issue is being progressed through Genuitec's support system. Yes, this scenario has been tested but there may be special circumstances in your set-up. A note to others watching: if a particular version of node is already installed somewhere, it can be copied to the .webclipse/nodejs/n.n.n folder in your home folder, where "n.n.n" is the version (for example "7.9.0"), which should stop it being downloaded during project initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent support getting through this really obscure folder permissions error. Finally got it workin !